OR function not working with arrayformula in Google Sheets
I want to use an arrayformula function to apply a formula across all rows in my sheet.
However, when adding the following formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(E2:E="English",E2:E="Spanish"),E2:E,"English"))

I don't get the desired result. It only works if the fomrula is added to each row, but this isn't going to work for me since I import a sheet weekly and want arrayformulas to apply data.
Edit this public sheet
The expected outcomes is in Column F. But column G, where the arrayformula is, doesn't do that.


Within arrayformula(); use + for OR and * for AND
So change this part of the formula
OR(E2:E="English",E2:E="Spanish")

to
(E2:E="English")+(E2:E="Spanish")


Thanks, man. This is great. I only found out about the * for AND yesterday, I didn't know OR was + for ARRAYFORMULA.
